# Why is my call to selection.join() not returning the enter selection?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I already managed to create some `<g>` tags using `selection.join()`. After doing the join I want to get a new selection of the complete list of all the existing `<g>` tags for method chaining, i.e., the ones that existed before plus the ones that have been created minus the ones that were destroyed. How do I get this from the `joinedNodes` variable?

```
 private createOrRemovePanelGroups(chartPanelsGroup: any, panelsRectangles: Array<Rectangle>): any {

    const joinedNodes: any = chartPanelsGroup
      .selectAll('g')
      .data(panelsRectangles)
      .join(
          enter => {
          enter.append('g');
      });
```

In the following second example the method takes a selected `<g>` in `selectedParentNode` and a descriptor of an rectangle. It has to draw the one and only rectangle here. I use an id to select it. In the first run it is created but it is not included in the selection returned by `.join()`. Hence, the last 4 lines are not executed for the newly created rectangle. However, those lines are executed if it is executed a second time and the rectangle is already existing, then the attributes are set.

```
static drawRectangle(selectedParentNode: any, rectangle: Rectangle, uniqueId: any, classStyle: any) {

selectedParentNode
  .selectAll('#' + uniqueId)
  .data([{rectangle}])
  .join(
    (enter: any) => {
      enter
        .append('rect')
        .attr('id', uniqueId);
    },
    (update: any) => update
  )
  .attr('x',  rectangle.getLeftX())
  .attr('y', rectangle.getTopY())
  .attr('width',  rectangle.getWidth())
  .attr('height', rectangle.getHeight())
  .attr('class', classStyle);
}
```

My specific problem can be boiled down to the following MCVE. Why is the selection returned by `.join()` empty?

```js
const joinedSelection = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data([1])
  .join(enter => { enter.append("p"); });
  
console.log(joinedSelection.empty());   // true -- Why is this selection empty?
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the words of the documentation:

> [#](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_join) *selection*.**join**(*enter*[, *update*][, *exit*]) [<>](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/selection/join.js)
>
> Appends, removes and reorders elements as necessary to match the data that was previously bound by [*selection*.data](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data), returning the [merged](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_merge) enter and update selection.

That means that `selection.join()` should already be returning the selection you are after, namely, the merged selections of the updated nodes as well as the newly entered ones. As you have witnessed yourself in your code that is not the case due to a small detail which is not covered by the documentation.

If you are passing in functions to `.join()` for a fine-grained control of what happens on enter, update, and exit the first two functions (enter and update) must return the respective selection they act on (i.e. return the enter or update selection, respectively)!

In your snippets the handler function for the enter selections is an arrow function executing a block of code which does not return any selection. Hence, the entering nodes are not included in the selection returned by `.join()`. Depending on the complexity of what those handler functions are doing there are basically two ways around this:

1. For simple cases just omit the curly brackets which will have the arrow function return the value of the expression:

   ```
   .join(enter => enter.append('g'));
   ```
2. For more complex cases you can easily return the selection from within the code block:

   ```
   .join(enter => {
     // ...do some serious stuff first.

     // append the entering nodes
     enter = enter.append("g")

     // ...followed by even more action.

     // Finally return the selection.
     return enter;
   }
   ```

Note, how this worked out right for the update selection in your second snippet where you were alreading using the above mentioned (1.) solution.

Your MCVE can easily be adjusted accordingly:

```js
const joinedSelection = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data([1])
  .join(enter => { return enter.append("p"); });
//  .join(enter => enter.append("p"));  // works as well
  
console.log(joinedSelection.empty());   // false, contains enter selection
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
```

---

**Rogue usage (not for the faint of heart)** — unrelated to your particular problem.

There is no restriction on the type of selection returned by the enter or the update handler functions; you might return just as well any selection, even an empty selection or a totally unrelated one. The selection returned by `.join()` comprises the returned selections by the enter and the update handler merged into one. Although I cannot come up with an application for this rather off-road usage it might be worth keeping this knowledge in the back of our heads.